# Php mail function giving "Error 550:sender is spammer" error?

Tags: php

This is my php code:

```
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Email Confirmation";
            $message="<h1>Welcome to asdasd.</h1>";
            $message .= "<br /><br /><br /><h4>This mail has been sent by asdasd.com to confirm your email account.</h4>";
            $message .= "<p>To confirm your email account and continue to the site click on the following link:</p>";
            $message .= "<a href=\"http://localhost/asd"\"\">click here to continue</a>";
            $message .= "<br /><br /><p>If you have not signed up using this email or <br/>if you want to cancel your singup click here</p>";
            $header = "From:myrealemail@gmail.com \r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
            ini_set("sendmail_from", "abcd@gmail.com");
            $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

What could be the problem?
I am using this server:smtp.bol.net.in
can i use localhost instead?

Comment: Have you checked to see if this mail server is in SMTP blocklists? If it is blacklisted, then you need to ask the server admin to get unblacklisted (he or she should know about this stuff, of course). Let me try... [yes, you've got problems](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3asmtp.bol.net.in&run=toolpage) - four blocklist failures at the time of my test.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", "abcd@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

are you run this code in localhost ? mail function doesn't work in localhost. 
and replace this row.

`$message .= "<a href='http://localhost/asd'>click here to continue</a>";`